# Why is "Task Status" being set to "Reassign Task"

Tags: designer-workflow

This is so bizarre. I have a workflow that is a custom Approval workflow and enables users to Request Changes and to Reassign Tasks too.

So I just realized instead of actually reassigning the task, it is just setting the Task Status to "Reassign Task" and leaving it assigned to the originator.

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue as well . Check out this Post:

http://blog.symprogress.com/2012/02/approval-workflow-changerequest-reassignment-stop-working/

Comment: Please add to your answer a summary of the solution from the link you provided. Link-only answers are not helpful when the link breaks in the future.